# Dictionary as value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

There is a dictionary with dictionaries as the value inside like so:

```
{'a': {'b': 'c', 'd': 'e', 'f': 'g'}, 'h': {'i': 'j', 'k': 'l', 'm': 'n'}}
```

How is it possible to access, let's say; the 'f' key (producing 'g') for 'a'?

Comment: Do you mean `d[a][f]` ?

Comment: `d.get("a", {}).get("f")` won't throw a keyError if  a key does not exdist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just chain key look-ups:

```
outer_dictionary['a']['f']
```

Here `dictionary['a']` returns the value for the key `'a'`, which is itself a dictionary.

You could also store the intermediary result:

```
nested_dictionary = outer_dictionary['a']
nested_dictionary['f']
```

This does the exact same thing, but also leaves another reference to the nested dictionary available as `nested_dictionary`.

Quick demo:

```
>>> nested_dictionary = {'a': {'b': 'c', 'd': 'e', 'f': 'g'}, 'h': {'i': 'j', 'k': 'l', 'm': 'n'}}
>>> nested_dictionary['a']
{'b': 'c', 'd': 'e', 'f': 'g'}
>>> nested_dictionary['a']['f']
'g'
```